# I check the values of a listview via a drop down list but I have white space left

Tags: c#, asp.net

sorry for the code I put in, but I don't know how.
[image]
I have a listview that is populated by a dropdown list and depending on the option it shows me some data, but the blank spaces remain for the information I don't use

both the dropdownlist and the listview are linked to two sqldatasources
Dropdownlist:

```
        <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="DenominazioneTipo" 
        DataValueField="IdTipo" AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
```

Listview:

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
     DataKeyNames="ID" InsertItemPosition="LastItem">
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table runat="server" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; 
               border-collapse: collapse; border-color:  
               #999999; border-style: none; border-width: 1px;">
                    <tr>
                   <td>Non è stato restituito alcun dato.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" 
      CommandName="Insert" Text="Inserisci" OnClick="InsertButton_Click" 
       Width="140px" />
                    </td>                    
                </tr>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="background-color: #FFFBD6; color: #333333;">
                    <td>
              <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" 
              CommandName="Delete" 
              Text="Elimina" OnClientClick="return confirm
              ('Confermi la cancellazione del record?');" />
              <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" 
              CommandName="Edit" Text="Modifica" ID_Persona='<%# 
              Eval("ID") %>' OnClick="EditButton_Click" />
                    </td>

                    <td>
                <asp:Label ID="NomeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# 
                 Eval("Nome") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="CognomeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Cognome") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="CodiceFiscaleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CodiceFiscale") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="RagioneSocialeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RagioneSociale") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="PivaLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Piva") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>



                <LayoutTemplate>
                <table runat="server">
                    <tr runat="server">
                        <td runat="server">

   <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="1" 
   style="background-color: #FFFFFF;
   border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #999999; 
   border-style: none; border-width: 1px;
     <tr runat="server" style="background-color: #FFFBD6; color:#333333;">
                <th runat="server"></th>
                <th runat="server">Nome</th>
                <th runat="server">Cognome</th>
                <th runat="server">CodiceFiscale</th>
                <th runat="server">Email</th>
                <th runat="server">RagioneSociale</th>
                <th runat="server">Piva</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                </tr>
                </table>
               </asp:ListView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Nome], [Cognome], [Email], [CodiceFiscale], [RagioneSociale], [Piva], [ID] FROM [Persona] WHERE ([Tipocliente] = @Tipocliente)" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Persona] WHERE [ID] = @original_ID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Persona] ([Nome], [Cognome], [Email], [CodiceFiscale], [RagioneSociale], [Piva]) VALUES (@Nome, @Cognome, @Email, @CodiceFiscale, @RagioneSociale, @Piva)" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Persona] SET [Nome] = @Nome, [Cognome] = @Cognome, [Email] = @Email, [CodiceFiscale] = @CodiceFiscale, [RagioneSociale] = @RagioneSociale, [Piva] = @Piva WHERE [ID] = @original_ID">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_ID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Nome" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Cognome" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CodiceFiscale" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="RagioneSociale" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Piva" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="Tipocliente" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="1" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Nome" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Cognome" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="CodiceFiscale" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="RagioneSociale" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Piva" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_ID" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

thank you in advance for your cooperation

Comment: Remove labels and parameters which is not useful for you.

Comment: what are they??

Comment: Nome, Cognome and CodiceFiscale i guess? Not sure if i understand your problem...

Comment: Nome cognome e codicefiscale they appear when another option is selected in the dropdwonlist, I want that when they are not needed they have to rise and appear only when the dropdownlist values them.

Comment: I'm on mobile now. So I can't edit your code write now. Do one thing . Add  some code in code behind file to check those three field are null or empy . If they are emty then hide them from code behind

Comment: how can I do? I'm sorry but I just started

Answer (score 0):

> **I'm getting error while adding this sample code in comment. So I
>   putting it in answer filed.   In code behind file add code just like
>   Please find appropriate event to do that
>   **

```
if(NomeLable.text !=null)
{ 
   NomeLable.visible = true ;
} 
else 
{
   NomeLable.visible = false;
 }
```

Comment: name label is not recognized to me, I don't know why

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting NomeLable in code behind file

Comment: public partial class Nuovapagina : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

Comment: protected void InsertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("/pages/Crea.aspx?Idtipo=" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
          
        }

        protected void EditButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(((Button)sender).Attributes["ID_Persona"]);
            Response.Redirect("/pages/Edit.aspx?Idtipo="+ DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "&ID_Persona=" + id);
        }
    }

Comment: that's all i have

Comment: Do one thing check the lable is null or not at text binding and accordingly run function to hide /unhide the label

Comment: Try to do it using JavaScript. For example <script type=text/javascript>  var labelNome = document.getElementById("<%#=NomeLable.ClientID%>");  window.onload(function ({ if   (labelNome =="") { labelNome.style.display =none } else { lableNome.style.dispaly = block }  ))</script>  Please check syntax on internet , I'm  sure I have syntax mistakes . Understand logic only.

Comment: he doesn't recognize me anyway